# How to transform the Magento order price in cents?

Tags: php, magento, casting

I have a nasty bug with payments in `Magento`, `Paybox` and `SOAP` web services, the idea is the following:

1. Payment is made in cents $36.37 = 3637cents (`Paybox` - API)
2. What I am trying to do is to transform my order price in cents in the following way:

   `$cents = $order->getBaseGrandTotal() * 100;`
3. Also I have a web service SOAP (strict types) that `respond` this `$cents` amount but it concerts it to `(int)`, then the magic happens sometimes the converted amount is not the expected one, the converted result is less than an cent, in my case it could be `3736`.

   ```
   $prices = array(39.8699, 12.3299, 11.3211);

   foreach ($prices as $price) {
       $stuff = round($price, 2) * 100;

       echo $stuff . PHP_EOL;
   }

   echo "After int conversion" . PHP_EOL;

   foreach ($prices as $price) {
       $stuff = (int) (round($price, 2) * 100);

       echo $stuff . PHP_EOL;
   }
   ```

The result is the following:

```
3987
1233
1132
After int conversion
3986
1233
1132
```

*Question*
Is there a way to fix this bug, it seems to be a php bug ?

Comment: Hint: `ini_set('precision', 20); var_dump($prices);`. Not a PHP bug: that's how computers work.

Comment: It's not a bug in php, it's a bug in your logic.  You'll have to deal with the trailing 4th and 5th digit in some way. The obvious answer would be to round up for larger than 50(4th and 5th digit). And not do anything for lesser than 50(4th and 5th digit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm summarises as this:

1. `$price = 39.8699; // 39.869900000000001228`
2. `round($price, 2) * 100; // 3986.9999999999995453`
3. `(int)3986.9999999999995453; // 3986`

You're rounding properly everywhere, except in the last step, where your  `(int)` casting truncates. Rounding would be more appropriate:

```
round($price * 100)
```

Said that, the root problem is that computers use binary logic and normally store numbers as base 2, while us humans use fuzzy logic and prefer base 10. There isn't much problem with "small" integers because there's a 1 to 1 correspondence but storing arbitrary base 10 floating points numbers in a fixed-sized base 2 representation is normally just an approximation. A classical example is **1.1** which has two digits in base 10 but is [periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) in base 2:

```
1.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101...
```

That's why common advice includes using exact data types when available (`DECIMAL` in your relational database, integers in your client code).

Comment: The casting isn't made by me its made by the Magento SOAP Handler, it casts my `float` into `int` and sometimes with less than a cent. At the cause of what you described...

Comment: Alright, I know nothing about Magento. I assume you haven't shared specific code because it's all transparent or something like that. If it's a platform bug perhaps you should report it to their bug tracker.